# How is it possible to call without implementing an abstract method in this Android's DB code?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm studying `Android` and I'm new to `DB`. I am trying to use the `Room` library to use the `DB`.

I'm looking at the sample code, but there's something I don't understand.

It is to call the `abstract method` of the `AppDatabase abstract class` without implementing it.

At least as far as I know, abstract classes cannot be instantiated.

But I'm curious how it can be called and how to use the returned value.
(Same for `Kotlin`.)

Am I wrong about `JAVA` or `Kotlin`?

***ToDoDao.interface***

```
@Dao // Data Access Object
interface ToDoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ToDo")
    abstract fun getAll(): List<ToDo>

    @Insert
    void insert(ToDo todo)

    @Update
    void update(ToDo todo)

    @Delete
    void delete(ToDo todo)
}
```

***AppDatabase.class***

```
@Database(entities = [Todo.class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract void TodoDao todotDao();
}
```

***Main.class***

```
AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase.class, "todo-db").build();

mResultTextView.setText(db.todoDao().getAll().toString); // THIS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't build database like this for simplicity , [this](https://github.com/sarafanshul/Habbit/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/projectdelta/habbit/data/TasksDatabase.kt) and [that](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts-v2/unit-4-saving-user-data/lesson-10-storing-data-with-room/10-1-c-room-livedata-viewmodel/10-1-c-room-livedata-viewmodel.html) are an example you can refer for building database and for accessing it use

```
val DB = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).ToDoDao ()
```